# Не работает grandlew.bat

Tags: android

Из Android Studio 2.3.3 проект нормально строится, но при запуске grandlew.bat выдает ошибку:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
   A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyApplication2'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools
/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build
/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom'.
               > Connection reset
```

Из браузера https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom скачивается нормально.

Содержимое grandle.build

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

содержимое gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#Sat Sep 08 10:03:37 MSK 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

В чем дело и как исправить?

Comment: JCenter как-то колбасит в последние дни, сталкивался с подобным. Просто запускать, пока не скачает.  И почему 2.3.3? 3.1.4 уже на дворе.

Comment: Сколько раз надо пробовать примерно? 10 раз уже попробовал. Я вообще не понимаю, зачем ему это скачивать, ведь если из самой студии компилируется, значит уже скачано. Студия какую поставил год назад, такая и стоит, новую ставить отдельный геморрой.

Comment: что за grandle такой? может быть gradle ..

Comment: AS и Gradle командной строки используют разные кэши. Один раз скачает, больше не будет просить. Еще проверьте прокси в системе, если есть.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте гугловский репозиторий, смотрю по логам, у меня все оттуда скачивает.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google() // gradle plugin 3+ only
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

**Дополнено**
Похоже, у Гугла плагин там хостится только с версии 3.0
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html

Хороший знак что пора уже обновить Android Studio :)

**Еще Дополнено**
На Maven Central от точно есть. Обновил ответ.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle/2.3.3

Comment: Я попробовал ваш вариант, все равно не работает. Не похоже, что дело в том, что файла нет. Т. к. вручную через браузер pom-файл у меня скачивается нормально. Новую версию ставить опасаюсь, т. к. может вообще все сломаться. Прокси у меня нет. Не подскажите, где эти 2 разных кеша находятся? Может быть можно скопировать один в другой?

Comment: Смотрите тогда антивирус и прочие подобные приложения, "защищающие" вас. Кто-то процессу Gradle доступ в интернет режет.

Comment: Я пробовал отключать антивирус и брандмауэр виндовс. Не помогло.